# Proving Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula and showing the following equality.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula:
>
> If $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ has a continuous derivative for $m \leq x \leq n $ then
>
> $\displaystyle \sum_{k=m} ^{n} f(k) = \int_m ^n f(x)$ $dx + \frac{1}{2} f(m) + \frac{1}{2} f(n) + \int_m ^n f'(x) n(x)$ $dx$,
>
> where $n(x) = x - [x] - \frac{1}{2}$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.
>
> Hint: For $m \leq k < n$ integrate by parts with $\int$ $dx = n(x) $to obtain
>
> $\displaystyle \int _{k} ^{k + \frac{1}{2}} f(x)$ $\displaystyle dx = \frac{1}{2} f(k) - \int _{k} ^{k + \frac{1}{2}} f'(x) n(x)$ $dx$ and
>
> $\displaystyle \int _{k + \frac{1}{2}} ^{k+1} f(x)$ $dx = \frac{1}{2} f(k+1) - \int _{k + \frac{1}{2}} ^{k+1} f'(x) n(x)$ $dx$,
>
> and sum over $k$. From this show that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^{- \alpha } = 
> \frac{n^{1- \alpha}}{1- \alpha } + c_{\alpha} + O(n^{- \alpha})$ if $0< \alpha < 1 $ for suitable constant $c_{\alpha}$.

This is a problem from Leveque's Number Theory. (Chapter 6, #3). All the section discussed is the following:

$f(x) = o(g(x))$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$.

$f(x) = O(g(x))$ if $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < M \in \mathbb{R}$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

$f(x)$ is asymptotically equal to $g(x)$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$.

There is a constant such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1} ^n \frac{1}{k} = \log n + \gamma + O(\frac{1}{n})$.

I am not sure how to start/proceed, even with the hint. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get what do you mean with $\int$ $dx = n(x) $....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the suggestions and take the sum (for $k = 1, \ldots , n-1$) of the combined result

$$\int_k^{k+1} f(x) \, dx = \frac1{2} f(k+1) + \frac1{2} f(k)  - \int_k^{k+1} f'(x) n(x) \, dx$$
You should get

$$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = \int_1^n f(x) \, dx  + \frac{1}{2}(f(n) + f(1)) + \int_1^n \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac1{2}\right) f'(x) \, dx.$$

With $f(x) = x^{-\alpha}$ and $f'(x) = -\alpha x^{-(\alpha+1)}$, everything should fall into place for the indicated result after you provide the estimate

$$\left|\int_1^n \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac1{2}\right) \frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} \, dx \right| \leqslant \int_1^n \left|x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac1{2}\right|\frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} \, dx \\ \leqslant\int_1^n \frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} \,dx \\= 1 - \frac{1}{n^\alpha}\\ = 1 +O(n^{-\alpha})$$

Comment: I see now! There is another question in the same section that says to show $\log (n!) = (n + \frac{1}{2}) \log n - n + O (log n)$ for $n>1$. Is there a way to use what we have in this question to deduce that as well? I checked that if you integrate $\int _{1}^{n} (n(x)/x) dx$ by parts then the error term could be improved to $C + O(n^{-1})$, but I am not sure if this serves much use.

Comment: Similar approach: Euler-Maclaurin with first-order remainder using the trick $\log n! = \log \prod_{k=1}^n k = \sum_{k=1}^n \log k = \int_1^n \log x \,dx + \ldots$

Comment: To the next order $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = \int_1^nf(x) \, dx + \frac1{2}(f(n) + f(1)) + \frac{1}{2}(f'(n) - f'(1)) + R_2$ where $R_2 = \frac1{2} \int_1^n B_2(x - \lfloor x \rfloor) f''(x) \, dx$ with $B_2(x)$ the Bernoulli polynomial of order 2.